# embed html inside google sheet

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I want to display HTML at the top of my spreadsheet by creating an html element and putting it at the top of my spreadsheet sheet.

For example, if I created one large cell at the top of my sheet by merging A1:G5, would it be possible to embed html within it:

```
<div>
 <h1>"Hello World"?</h1>
</div>
```

I notice from within script editor you can go file > new > html file.

But I don't really get it's purpose.

I just tried this:
From script editor new script:

```
function addSomeHTML() {
  var html = HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile('cabbages')
      .setSandboxMode(HtmlService.SandboxMode.IFRAME);
}
```

Cabbages is an html file:

```
<div>
  <h1>Hello, world!</h1>
</div>
```

I then saved and navigated to my sheet. I selected a cell and typed `=addSomeHTML()`

The "loading" message appeared then an empty cell was shown. I was hoping to see "Hello World!" within the cell.

I've looked at the following documentation:

https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/html/templates#printing_scriptlets

https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/dialogs

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can use either a Modal or Modeless dialog box.

The Modal dialog uses the `showModalDialog()` method of the Ui Class.

[Guide to Dialogs](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/dialogs)

[Google Documentation - Modal Dialog](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/base/ui#showModalDialog(Object,String))

### Add a custom menu to the spreadsheet

```
// This will run when the spreadsheet is opened or the browser page is refreshed
function onOpen() {
  SpreadsheetApp.getUi()
      .createMenu('Custom Menu')
      .addItem('Open Dialog Box', 'openDialog')
      .addToUi();
}
```

### Create the function that runs from the menu

```
function openDialog() {
  var html = HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile('index');

  SpreadsheetApp.getUi()
    .showModalDialog(html, 'Correct Postcode Errors');
}
```

### index.html

```
<div>
 <h1>"Hello World"?</h1>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to answer. I did see that tutorial and went through those steps. The modal dialogue is not what I was hoping for though. Is it possible to embed html outside of this pop up box?

Comment: You can put HTML in a sidebar.

Comment: OK. But not within the main part of the sheet?

Comment: Not that I know of, no.  You could create an HTML Stand Alone App with a spreadsheet embedded in the app.

Comment: OK good to know, thanks. Leaving the question open for a little longer

Comment: went with Modeless dialogue box in the end. Thanks again