# Render HTML content to google spreadsheet

Tags: html, google-apps-script, google-sheets, render

I've an HTML content in cell A1, I want to render the HTML content and add the rendered HTML content in cell B1

e.g. if I've this HTML in A1

```
<label class="s-label mb4 d-block" for="wmd-input">
                    Body

                        <p class="s-description mt2">Include all the information someone would need to answer your question</p>
                </label>
```

I want the output in B1 to be

```
Body
Include all the information someone would need to answer your question
```

I've tried

```
  var htmlTarget = current.getRange('A1').getValue();
  var htmlOutput = HtmlService.createHtmlOutput(htmlTarget);
  var message = htmlOutput.getContent();
  database.getRange('B1').setValue(message);
```

And it gets the same HTML and pastes it with the tags without rendering anything

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27787074/embed-html-inside-google-sheet ?

Comment: I don't have a file that contains the HTML it's in the cell. so I've tried

  var htmlTarget = current.getRange('A1').getValue();
  var htmlOutput = HtmlService.createHtmlOutput(htmlTarget);
  var message = htmlOutput.getContent();
  database.getRange('A2').setValue(message);

And it doesn't work

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe your goal as follows.

- You want to convert the HTML data to the plain text data using Google Apps Script.

#### Modification points:

- The method of `getContent()` in Class HtmlOutput returns the HTML data. [Ref](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/html/html-output#getContent()) I thought that this might be the reason of your issue.

In order to retrieve the rendered text without the HTML tags, in this answer, I would like to propose to retrieve the text data by converting the HTML data to Google Document using the method of "Files: insert" in Drive API v2. (Because, the version of Drive API is still v2 at Advanced Google service.)

When your script is modified, it becomes as follows.

#### Modified script:

Before you use this script, [please enable Drive API at Advanced Google services](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/services/advanced#enabling_advanced_services).

From:

```
var htmlTarget = current.getRange('A1').getValue();
var htmlOutput = HtmlService.createHtmlOutput(htmlTarget);
var message = htmlOutput.getContent();
database.getRange('B1').setValue(message);
```

To:

```
var htmlTarget = current.getRange('A1').getValue();
var blob = Utilities.newBlob(htmlTarget, MimeType.HTML);
var id = Drive.Files.insert({title: "sample", mimeType: MimeType.GOOGLE_DOCS}, blob).id;
var message = DocumentApp.openById(id).getBody().getText();
DriveApp.getFileById(id).setTrashed(true); //  or Drive.Files.remove(id);
database.getRange('B1').setValue(message);
```

- In this modified script, the following flow is run.

  1. Convert HTML data to Google Document as a temporal file.
  2. Retrieve text data from Google Document.
  3. Remove the temporal file.
  4. Put the text data to the cell.

#### References:

- [getContent()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/html/html-output#getcontent)
- [Files: insert](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v2/reference/files/insert)

Comment: @basel adel Thank you for replying. I'm glad your issue was resolved.