# Is it possible to display an iframe or webview in google sheets

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, webview

I have a google sheets file with just URLs of products.

I want to create some iframe/webview/view inside the sheet that can load the contents of that url in that view.

For e.g. when i select any cell with the product url the webview/iframe loads the contents of that url.

Is it possible?

Picture attached for reference on how it would look like.
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can easily achieve it using [Google Apps Script](https://developers.google.com/apps-script).

These are the steps to follow:

1. Inside your sheet go to `Extensions`>`Apps Script`
2. Inside the Code.gs, create an [`onOpen(e)`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers#onopene) function for adding a custom Menu when the Sheets is opened by the user.

```js
const onOpen = (e) => {
  SpreadsheetApp.getUi()
    .createMenu('Preview Content')
    .addItem('Show', 'previewProduct')
    .addToUi();
}
```

3. This will trigger a function when the user clicks on the menu.
4. Creating the function `previewProduct`

```js
const previewProduct = () => {
  /* Gets the actual user cell */
  /* You may want to implement some kind of control of what values */
  /* can be slected */
  /* ex. if(!value.match(urlRegex)) return */
  
  const range = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveRange()
  const value = range.getValue()
  if(value===null) return
  /* Fetchs the content and parse it as html */
  const html = UrlFetchApp.fetch(value).getAs('text/html')
  /* Creates an Output with the fetched HTML */
  /* You have two alternatives */
  /* Creating a Modal Dialog */
  const htmlOutput = HtmlService
    .createHtmlOutput(html)
    .setWidth(720)
    .setHeight(720);
  SpreadsheetApp.getUi().showModalDialog(htmlOutput, 'My add-on');
  /* Creating a Sidebar */
  SpreadsheetApp.getUi().showSidebar(HtmlService.createHtmlOutput(html))
}
```

5. Reopen the Spreadsheet, put the cursor in one cell, and click on  `Preview Content` > `Show`

[image: Results]

###### Documentation

- [`UrlFetchApp`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/url-fetch/url-fetch-app)
- [Ui inside Google Apps Script](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/base/ui)
- [`getActiveRange()`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/spreadsheet-app#getactiverange)

Comment: Thanks @emel. 
Would it be possible to display the contents of the url in a cell, instead of a popup?

Comment: You have formulas as [`IMPORTHTML`](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093339?hl=en) that allows you to import list or table form html

Comment: If you want to display the data inside a cell you can follow this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64835726/render-html-content-to-google-spreadsheet). Simply change the htmlTarget to the one obtained from `UrlFetchApp`, also, add `getDataAsString` to it.

Answer (score 0):

this is the solution.

```
=arrayformula(LET(
  id, IF(REGEXMATCH(C2:C, "https://drive.google.com/"), REGEXEXTRACT(C2:C, "id=([^&]+)"), C2:C),
  url, IF(REGEXMATCH(id, "^http"), C2:C, "https://drive.google.com/uc?id=" & id),
  HYPERLINK(url, IMAGE(url))
))
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).