# How to get HTML code from within a google sheet cell and render it so it's visible within another cell

Tags: html, google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-drive-api

Within a google sheet, I'm attempting to get HTML code from Column F on Tab2 and render it so its visible on Column G of tab 2 within the same row.

e.g I have the html code below in F6 and I want to render it to G6. Generally the code is much longer.

```
<p>Dear Person,</p><p>the time is almost here!</p><p>Your itinerary is included below. Please print this and carry it with you.</p><p>Have a great day! </p>
```

I've attempted following another question linked below, but my knowledge is still very minimal and I was unable to adjust it to work.

[Render HTML content to google spreadsheet](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64835726/render-html-content-to-google-spreadsheet)

```
var htmlTarget = current.getRange('A1').getValue();
var blob = Utilities.newBlob(htmlTarget, MimeType.HTML);
var id = Drive.Files.insert({title: "sample", mimeType: MimeType.GOOGLE_DOCS}, blob).id;
var message = DocumentApp.openById(id).getBody().getText();
DriveApp.getFileById(id).setTrashed(true); //  or Drive.Files.remove(id);
database.getRange('B1').setValue(message);
```

Comment: You have not provided any html content

Comment: @cooper my apologies, I pasted it normally but edited it.

Comment: First, I apologize that my answer was not useful for your situation. From `I was unable to adjust it to work.`, I proposed the modified script for your situation. Could you please confirm it? If I misunderstood `I was unable to adjust it to work.`, I apologize.

Answer (score 0):

From your showing script, I thought that `current` and `database` are required to be declared in your situation. I thought that this might be the reason for `I was unable to adjust it to work.`. So, how about the following modification?

#### Modified script 1:

In this pattern, your showing script is modified. Please set your sheet name and [please enable Drive API at Advanced Google services](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/services/advanced#enabling_advanced_services).

```js
function myFunction() {
  var current = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Sheet1"); // Please set your sheet name.
  var htmlTarget = current.getRange('F6').getValue();
  var blob = Utilities.newBlob(htmlTarget, MimeType.HTML);
  var id = Drive.Files.insert({ title: "sample", mimeType: MimeType.GOOGLE_DOCS }, blob).id;
  var message = DocumentApp.openById(id).getBody().getText();
  DriveApp.getFileById(id).setTrashed(true); //  or Drive.Files.remove(id);
  current.getRange('G6').setValue(message);
}
```

#### Modified script 2:

Please set your sheet name and [please enable Sheets API at Advanced Google services](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/services/advanced#enabling_advanced_services).

```js
function myFunction() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var current = ss.getSheetByName("Sheet1"); // Please set your sheet name.
  var htmlTarget = current.getRange('F6').getValue();
  Sheets.Spreadsheets.batchUpdate({ requests: [{ pasteData: { html: true, data: `<table><tr><td>${htmlTarget}</td></tr></table>`, coordinate: { sheetId: current.getSheetId(), rowIndex: 5, columnIndex: 6 } } }] }, ss.getId());
}
```

#### Modified script 3:

Please set your sheet name and [please enable Drive API at Advanced Google services](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/services/advanced#enabling_advanced_services). And also, please install a Google Apps Script library of RichTextApp (Author me). [Ref](https://github.com/tanaikech/RichTextApp#documenttospreadsheet)

```js
function myFunction() {
  var current = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Sheet1"); // Please set your sheet name.
  var htmlTarget = current.getRange('F6').getValue();
  var blob = Utilities.newBlob(htmlTarget, MimeType.HTML);
  var id = Drive.Files.insert({ title: "sample", mimeType: MimeType.GOOGLE_DOCS }, blob).id;
  var doc = DocumentApp.openById(id);
  var range = current.getRange('G6');
  var res = RichTextApp.DocumentToSpreadsheet({ range: range, document: doc });
  DriveApp.getFileById(id).setTrashed(true); //  or Drive.Files.remove(id);
  console.log(res);
}
```

- For all modified scripts, the cells of "F6" and "G6" of "Sheet1" are used. The cell value of "F6" is retrieved and the retrieved HTML is rendered and the value is put into the cell "G6".

#### References:

- Related thread.

  - [Render HTML content to google spreadsheet](https://stackoverflow.com/q/64835726)
- [Method: spreadsheets.batchUpdate](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/v4/spreadsheets/batchUpdate)
- [RichTextApp](https://github.com/tanaikech/RichTextApp)